# unserialize(): Error at offset 5399 of 11300 bytes in /home1/chiqmvaz/public_html/admin/model/extension/module/so_megamenu.php on line 150Notice

Tags: php, opencart, categories, opencart-module

I am getting this error on open cart and my sub categories are not visible on front page. Any solution appreciated!

> unserialize(): Error at offset 5399 of 11300 bytes in /home1/chiqmvaz/public_html/admin/model/extension/module/so_megamenu.php on line 150Notice
> : Undefined index: categories in /home1/chiqmvaz/public_html/admin/controller/extension/module/so_megamenu.php on line 538

Comment: There's a error in the format of the string you're trying to unserialize, and you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist in the `categories` array. We can't tell you much more than what the error states with current information. The fix at present is to not do those things.

Comment: Try to clear opencart cache

Comment: i have tried but nothing happened